# Import QML module from resource file

Tags: qt, qml

The following project structure is working for import a qml module:

Project structure

```
Project
|- modules
    |- Goofy
       |- qmldir
       |- Donald.qml
|- project.pro
|- main.cpp
|- main.qml
|- qml.qrc
```

project.pro

```
QT += quick

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += \
   modules/Goofy/Donald.qml \
   modules/Goofy/qmldir \
   qml.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/modules
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/modules
```

main.cpp

```
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   engine.addImportPath("qrc:/modules");
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import Goofy 1.0

Window {
   width: 640
   height: 480
   visible: true
   title: qsTr("Hello World")

   Donald{}
}
```

qmldir

```
module Goofy
Donald 1.0 Donald.qml
```

How should I modify my project to import the module **from a qrc file** instead of adding any single file to the resources??

Ideally I'd like to have the following pro file:

project.pro

```
QT += quick

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += \
   modules/Goofy/goofy.qrc \ 
   qml.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/modules
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD/modules
```

I tried adding goofy.qrc (or Goofy.qrc) to my modules/Goofy folder with the following format:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qmldir</file>
        <file>Donald.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Goofy.rcc doesn't work because the files are not located in the used importPath. The files are next to the qrc, so no relative path is added to the specified prefix. Alter the rcc to the following to make it work:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/modules/Goofy">
        <file>qmldir</file>
        <file>Donald.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

As you already seem to understand, the qmldir file needs to be in the `Goofy` path for the QmlEngine to accept it. Add that to the specified import path and QmlEngine will find your module, just like it's on disk (since qrc is actually rendered as a normal filesystem)

BTW, You can check the working of relative qrc paths with the following snippet:

```
QDirIterator qrc(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while(qrc.hasNext())
{
    qDebug() << qrc.next();
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks god! I already tried modifying the rcc prefix, but I tried just prefix="/Goofy" not considering the whole path. I'm going to give you the bounty.

Comment: (replying to a deleted message, why it is not visible in designer) Yes, because the importPath of the designer is not set to your qrc file. I'm not sure that can be done. In my projects I have opted for exporting the module to my Qt folder (next to being in the resource for the app itself)

Comment: Thank you again. I deleted it because I'm able to see it, it's just from main.qml which don't show nothing, but I have the same issue even with the solution without resource file so I guess it's not related.

Comment: I hardly ever use the designer since it crashed so often on me... You might be able to make it work when running Qt Creator with the QML2_IMPORT_PATH environment var set correctly (which requires that you have the correct qmldir structure on disk as well)

Comment: What do you mean with correct qmldir structure on disk?

Comment: That the Goofy module qmldir file should be in <importPath>/Goofy/qmldir and Goofy.util in <importPath>/Goofy/util/qmldir